# Error in data(): "TypeError: Unable to get property 'questions' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am getting this error `Error in data(): "TypeError: Unable to get property 'questions' of undefined or null reference"` on the template page. What am I doing wrong here I could not resolve the error. It appears to be quiz.questions is not recognized by the template even though data() has the quiz variable. Below is the vue routing and the template Question.vue that needs to be rendered on the front page.

**Routing**

```
let routes = [
{ path: '/quiz/:id(\\d+)/', component: require('./components/Questions.vue') },
```

**Question.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="ques_wrapper">
        <div v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions" class="ques_block">

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    data() {
         return {
          quiz: {
                title: 'My quiz',
                questions: [
                  {
                    text: "Question 1",
                    responses: [
                      {text: 'Wrong, too bad.'}, 
                      {text: 'Right!', correct: true}, 
                    ]
                  }, {
                    text: "Question 2",
                    responses: [
                      {text: 'Right answer', correct: true}, 
                      {text: 'Wrong answer'}, 
                    ]
                  } 
                ]
              },
              questionIndex: 0,
              userResponses: Array(this.quiz.questions.length).fill(false)
            }
        },

        // The view will trigger these methods on click

        methods: {

          // Go to next question

          next: function() {

            this.questionIndex++;

          },

          // Go to previous question

          prev: function() {

            this.questionIndex--;

          },

          // Return "true" count in userResponses

          score: function() {

            return this.userResponses.filter(function(val) { return val }).length;

          }

        }

    }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your userResponses variable should be a computed property, so remove it from data and add this between data() and methods :

```
computed:{
userResponses(){return Array(this.quiz.questions.length).fill(false)} 
}
```

Check the documentation for more informations about computed properties :
https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your vue instance already ran before the data was loaded. 
Try adding a `v-if` to check if the data already exists before vue loads the data.

```
<div v-if="quiz" v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions" class="ques_block">

</div>
```

Comment: I  am getting the same error even after adding v-if="quiz"

Comment: maybe it's because of this line: `userResponses: Array(this.quiz.questions.length).fill(false)`? can you try removing that line and see if the errors still appears

Comment: if not there, what is your idea why does that error show? maybe you have other files using `questions` without being defined

Comment: Property or method "quiz" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

Comment: I am trying to alter code from https://codeburst.io/create-a-quiz-with-vue-js-ed1e8e0e8294